# Text colour in R markdown ioslides/js. reveal slides

Tags: r, r-markdown, ioslides

I see from the R Markdown [website](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/ioslides_presentation_format.html#text_color) that the colour of text can be changed like so:

```
<div class="red2">
This text is red
</div>
```

But this doesn't seem to work for text formatted with `, like "If in doubt, use `?dplyr::filter`", for example. 
Besides using css or html tags, is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Did you try `<style> .red2 { color: red2 !important; } </style>`

Comment: Thanks Martin, but that didn't work, nothing showed. I found a solution and posted it as an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after poking around it seems that the quickest way to do this is with a html `<style>` tag. I was looking for something that avoided css or html, but this seems to be the best way to do this. There are plenty of options, but a simple one is:

```
If in doubt, use <bdi style="color:red;">`?dplyr::filter`</bdi> to get help.
```